Send case survey invitation to case suppliedEmail field when case is closed
I have created one survey to collect customer feedback. Now I want to send it to supplied email field on case. Checked on case auto response rule and also in Support settings - Customer Feedback Survey but not able to find a way to send it to case's suppliedEmail field. Also created one flow but in that also I am not able to find a way to send it to case's suppliedEmail. Is there any way from which we can send the survey to this field?


From Case Auto-Response Rules:
In field you can map Case: Web Email which is basically SuppliedEmail (api name).

From Salesforce Flow:
You need to create a formula field on case object let's say Sample Email, which can get the value of Web Email and that field can be used in


Select the apex action named "Send Survey Invitation".

Configure Survey Name and for Survey Recipient select
{!$Record.Sample_Email__c}.
Configure the required fields and trigger the flow it should send the
survey to respective email address configured.


I can only see three options - user in your org, contact and lead for sending the invites. Invites can only be sent to these ids. I get error when I select email or any other field.

In salesforce flow add action named "Send Survey Invitation" and give it a try instead of selecting survey action.
